# Windows 8: Explorer List View - Spacing has suddenly changed between columns

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I think something has changed in the Registry that has altered the was folders are displayed in Explorer's List View, which I have always used pretty much for all folders.

It USED to be that the space between columns in the folders would compact in each column where there was no wasted space between columns.  Each column would ONLY be as wide as the widest file / folder IN THAT COLUMN.  If the next column over had, say, files with shorter names, let's say the longest being 10 characters, then THAT column would adjust to being ONLY 10 characters across.

NOW, it is not doing that.  It has somehow reverted to what I THINK is general behaviour for Explorer, and now EVERY column is set to the widest file name in the whole folder.  So, if say the longest file name is 30 characters, now EVERY column is 30 characters wide, wasting a LOT of space within the folders.

I don't remember if I had incorporated a Registry tweak to get it the way it was and if it has simply reverted to general behaviour.  So, I thought I would ask this here to see if ANYONE knows how I can get the Explorer column width BACK to where each column adjusts to JUST what it needs widthwise for THAT column ONLY.

Thank you all so much for any help!